# ASP.NET MVC 5 - How do I present an external URL so that the server's IP is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a 3rd party service that I have to connect that has the following requirement. Call a URL using the SERVER's IP address, then present the resultant html to the client.

Redirect(URL) is not working as it passes the client IP address. Is there a way to direct a client to an external URL so that the external server thinks it is coming from the server and not the client?

The 3rd party company has been no help at all, they just keep telling me I have to call their "service" from my server and pass the results to the client. Admittedly I am still a novice developer, but this "service" seems more like a website (which I understand can be considered a service) rather than a RESTful or WFC service that I am used to.

Comment: User visits your website (your controller gets called), Your controller does the GET/POST request to the service and receives some HTML, your Controller returns a View and passes the HTML from the service along, your View renders the HTML from the service.

Comment: Thanks Felix, that does indeed work (sort of).  Now to get this 3rd party to change all their css and js links to not be relative links, and I think this might actually work...